# How can I create a view with variant columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have table `tbl_settings` that always has only one record. and a field `show_messages_in_log` in it. and another `table tbl_logs` stores all logs. Of course, `tbl_logs` has a message field.

I need a view to show logs:

- If `tbl_settings.show_messages_in_log` is true , show `tbl_logs.message`,
- If `tbl_settings.show_messages_in_log` is false , not to show `tbl_logs.message`.

Can any body help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. In a relational database relations (tables, views) always have to have a fixed number of columns.

The only thing you can do is to always have that column, but display it as NULL in the view. For that you will need to join the two tables and the use a case expression in the view:

```
case 
   when show_messages_in_log = 'true' then tbl_logs.message
   else null
end as message
```

Comment: in a stored procedure I can use multiple selects based upon  tbl_settings.show_messages_in_log. but in view , it's not available.

Comment: @alirakiyan: I have no idea what you mean with your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just join the tables, like this

```
create table tbl_settings 
(show_messages_in_log boolean);

create table tbl_logs
(message varchar(200));

insert into tbl_logs
values ('msg1'), ('msg2');

insert into tbl_settings 
values (true);

select tbl_logs.message
from tbl_logs inner join tbl_settings on tbl_settings.show_messages_in_log = TRUE
```

This will return all the rows.

```
update tbl_settings set show_messages_in_log = false;

select tbl_logs.message
from tbl_logs inner join tbl_settings on tbl_settings.show_messages_in_log = TRUE
```

This will return no row at all.

Comment: in a stored procedure I can use multiple selects based upon tbl_settings.show_messages_in_log. but in view , it's not available. is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF tbl_settings.show_messages_in_log = TRUE THEN tbl_logs.message
ELSE NULL
END IF
```

Comment: In View you can not do such thing my friend.